# How to prevent my site getting caught in Google's child porn filter?

Tags: filtering

After [Google and Microsoft take steps to block Internet search results linked to child porn](http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/11/18/google-and-microsoft-take-steps-to-block-internet-search-results-linked-to-child-porn), one of my sites which was about kid's photography got blocked in many search results. Actually my site is 100% clean of any pornography and it's been blocked by mistake. The filtering takes into effect when there are keywords like `kid` or `boy` in the user's query. I've lost almost 100% of my Google traffic recently. A query like `site:mysite.com kid` would return no results but `site:mysite.com somethingelse` works fine. I've received no message in my Webmaster's tools account about it either.

How can I get back my site up the search results again? My site is clean and it's Google mistake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Actually my site is 100% clean of any pornography and it's been blocked by mistake

If your site isn't appearing in Google search results, or it's performing more poorly than it once did (and you believe that it does not violate Google Webmaster Guidelines), you can ask Google to reconsider your site.

- First, review the [Manual Actions page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/answer.py?answer=2604824) to see if Google has found any
  issues with your site.
- Request reconsideration of your site.

**Request reconsideration of your site:**

1. **Sign in to Webmaster Tools** with your Google Account.
2. Make sure you have added and verified the site you want reconsidered.
3. [Request reconsideration of your site](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration?pli=1).

See this [link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35843?hl=en) for more information.